# How to fetch all the deployed commits from octokit github client for ruby?

Tags: ruby, github-api, octokit

I am using the ruby `Ocktokit` to fetch deployments (list_deployments). At present it only lists the latest 30. I need to filter this on the basis of payload and need to access all deployments till date.

The Github Api provides a link in the header to access the next page. Is there something similar in Ocktokit?

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(
  :access_token => ENV.fetch("GITHUB_TOKEN"),
)

repo = "repo_name"
env  = "env_name"
options = {
    :environment => env,
    :task => "task_name"
  }

deployments = client.deployments(repo, options)
```

Comment: You should include in your question the code you're using to generate an API response and then the output you get from ocktokit. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octokit provides [pagination](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#pagination) but also auto-pagination.

You may be able to do something like:

```
client.auto_paginate = true
deployments = client.deployments 'username/repository' # same as list_deployments
deployments.length
```

Update: I tested this locally and pagination in this manner, while documented, doesn't work as expected for deployments. You'll need to fetch the deployments manualy.

The [deployment documentation](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Deployments.html) indicated that listing all deployments should be available in the latest version.

If that doesn't work you may need to do it manually:

```
# fetch your first list of deployments
deployments = client.deployments 'username/repository'

while true
  begin
    deployments.concat client.last_response.rels[:next].get.data
    puts deployments.length
    break if deployments.length > 500
  rescue StandardError
    puts 'quitting'
  end
end

puts deployments.length
```

Comment: I tried `auto_paginate = true` that didn't work. The documentation mentions that all deployments will be listed but the function only returns the first 30 even when auto_paginate is true. I tried to do it manually in a loop by concat that works but how can i know how many pages to loop through?

Comment: @sparkstar Which version of the gem are you using? And are you hitting the v3 API, or v4? I would just do a while loop until I hit an error. Then once you figure out what that error is modify your code to rescue from it. I don't have time to work up an example right now but will this evening.

Comment: @sparkstar can you try setting the results per. Page also? https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/README.md#default-results-per_page see if you can even change that

Comment: `octokit (4.13.0)` and `v3` API

Comment: @sparkstar I tested the gem myself and updated my answer. auto paginate doesn't work for deployments per the docs. You can put the get in a `while true`. My code sample is updated to reflect that and an early quit method.

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear to respect the client level per_page settings either

Comment: Yup! I checked it as well using the loop for the time being hope they update it!